# SQL server database engine services installation issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, installation

I am in process of installing SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition. I have installed SQL Server Reporting Services and Analysis Services but I can't install the database engine services .

When I try to install, I am getting an error:

> The required MSI package 'I:\SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition\x86\setup....\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup.' doesn't exist

I checked the path which contain like shown, so my question is am I missing any msis? [image: sql msis]

**EDIT**

I already have visual studio 2008 and 2012 installed does it make any issues to exisitng??

Comment: is your machine 32-bit ?

Comment: @M.Ali yes my system is 32 bit

Comment: well your installer doesnt seem to have `x86` folders, which contains files for 32-bit installations. Are you sure your Installer support 32 Bit installation ?

Comment: @M.Ali i edited my question, if that is the case how i can install reporting services and analysys one